# Laravel relationship not working: getConnectionName() Error

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, relation

I have two tables `users` and `user_details`. I have linked `users` table as

```
public function userDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Repositories\Models\UserDetails', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

and linked `user_details` table as

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Repository\Models\User');
}
```

While from `UserController` for accessing users data with details, if I try to access the data

```
return $this->user->with('userDetails')->get();
```

I get this type of error

```
FatalErrorException in HasRelationships.php line 488: Call to undefined method

App\Repositories\Models\UserDetails::getConnectionName()
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure `UserDetails` class extends `Model` class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDetails extends Model
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also clean up your code like this. Having neat code will make your code more valuable and it will be easier for other developers to understand or you to remember when you get back to your code later on.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Repository\Models\User;
use App\Repository\Models\UserDetails;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function userDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('UserDetails', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Will sure do. I used `User::class` and `UserDetails::class`.